# REACT (cra): When trying to use jQuery in fullcalendar's "eventRender" I get the error: $el.popover is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar, tooltip, popover

I am trying to implement the popover option in the calendar events using the suggested implementation from [fullcalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-tooltip-demo), but when I write the callback function that uses popover method and jQuery, I get the error:

> TypeError: $el.popover is not a function

Here's a fraction of my code.

```
class CalendarComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.init();
    }  

  init = () => {
    [...]

        $('#calendar').data("activityAssignedEvents", activityAssignedEvents);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: false,
            defaultView: "timelineDay",
            height: "auto",
            slotLabelFormat: "HH",

            // businessHours: businessHours,
            themeSystem: "bootstrap4",
            slotLabelInterval: "02:00:00",
            slotDuration: "01:00:00",
            nowIndicator: true,
            now: moment.utc(),
            timezone: "local",
            locale: "pt-br",
            events: activityAssignedEvents,
            eventRender: function (eventObj, $el) {
                $el.popover({
                    title: eventObj.title,
                    content: eventObj.description,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement: 'top',
                    container: 'body'
                });
            },

        });
  }
}
```

My imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem.

I've already tried updating jQuery and Bootstrap versions using npm, but nothing changed.

Comment: You haven't loaded the popover library in to the page

Comment: After importing:
*import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';* and *import 'popper.js/dist/popper.min.js'*, which I am not sure are the libraries used, but I am assuming looking for the [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001) I get the following error:

_TOOLTIP: Option "content" provided type "undefined" but expected type "(string|element|function)"._

Answer (score 0):

few ideas.. try:

1. `$el = $($el);` in the eventRender function before you use `$el.popover(...` (it might not be a jQuery object)
2. Add the calendar library js file and jquery to your header inside index.html
3. Make sure the script executes after you load the libraries

Comment: Well, tried:
1. Did not work.
2. Since it is React, I am doing the imports in the component. 3. I am not sure how to check that besides using componentDidMount lifecycle